# Map<String,wrapper> returned from apex class, not received by the helper controller!

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, helper

I am returning a map value from the apex controller, but the helper controller doesn't receive anything data. Here the system.debug outputs the right values to be received by the controller. Plz advise!

```
public static Map<String,unitDetails> getMdus() {
  Map<String,unitDetails> mdus = new Map<String,unitDetails>();
         //Code that populates the variables here

           unitDetails mdu = new unitDetails();
            mdu.activeUnits = activeUnits;
            mdu.neverUnits = neverUnits;
            mdu.coldUnits = coldUnits;
            mdu.internetOfferings = internetOfferings;
            mdu.videoOfferings = videoOfferings;
            mdu.phoneOfferings = phoneOfferings;
            mdu.singlePlays = singlePlays;
            mdu.doublePlays = doublePlays;
            mdu.triplePlays = triplePlays;

            mdus.put('bldg',mdu);
            system.debug(mdus);
        } 
        return mdus;
} 
public class unitDetails {
        public Integer activeUnits {get; set;}
        public Integer neverUnits {get; set;}
        public Integer coldUnits {get; set;}
        public Integer internetOfferings {get; set;}
        public Integer videoOfferings {get; set;}
        public Integer phoneOfferings {get; set;}
        public Integer singlePlays {get; set;}
        public Integer doublePlays {get; set;}
        public Integer triplePlays {get; set;}
    }
```

Comment: What's the context here? Lightning? Visualforce? Something else?

Comment: @sfdcfox - Lightning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Lightning, you must use [`@AuraEnabled`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_auraenabled_annotation.htm) in order to have the data be serialized.

```
public class unitDetails {
    @AuraEnabled public Integer activeUnits;
    @AuraEnabled public Integer neverUnits;
    @AuraEnabled public Integer coldUnits;
    @AuraEnabled public Integer internetOfferings;
    @AuraEnabled public Integer videoOfferings;
    @AuraEnabled public Integer phoneOfferings;
    @AuraEnabled public Integer singlePlays;
    @AuraEnabled public Integer doublePlays;
    @AuraEnabled public Integer triplePlays;
}
```

Comment: @Sumchans You're welcome!